# How could I access a SWRevealViewController Table Cell so that I can performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a **SWRevealViewController** that opens a side menu, from which I connected the segue manually in my Storyboard. I want to programmatically use **performSegueWithIdentifier** once a cell is clicked, but I don't know how to access the "Cell Clicked" method of the table. Does anybody have experience with this particular library that might know how to do this?

Comment: You can subclass and/or access each of the controllers directly from each other using the reveal controller property of each view controller that's a part of it. It's something like self.revealViewController().rightViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {



    SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;
    revealController.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    UIViewController *objViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objViewController];
    [revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];


 }
```

Use this